# Certain orthogonal connection on the unit tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume  that  $M$  is   a  compact  Riemannian  manifold. The  unit  tangent  bundle of  $M$  is  denoted  by  $SM$  with the  natural  projection $p:SM \to M$.

A  connection on $SM$  is  a  distribution for  $SM$  with trivial  intersection with  the  vertical distribution $\ker  Dp$

> Is  there always  a  connection $T $ on $SM$  with the following  property?:
>
> For  every  $(x,v) \in SM$ we  have  $Dp(T_{(x,v)}) \perp  v$

If  the  answer  is  yes, can  we  always  chose such type  of  connection with   dimension $n-1$?

Comment: Am I interpreting you correctly: $n$ is the dimension of $M$, and you've relaxed the usual requirement that a connection intersects the vertical bundle transversely to simply intersecting trivially.

Comment: Of course, this is not a connection in the usual sense. What is it good for I do not know. For instance, you cannot define parallel transport using it (except for some special paths in the base), you cannot define a covariant derivative, etc. What is your motivation?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes  Of  course my  terminology  is  not  appropriate.

Comment: @MoisheCohen  I  will  explain  My  motivation  in separate question  because  it  is   not  short  to  write  in a  comment.Thank you  for  your  attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since parallel translates of unit vectors are unit vectors, the Riemannian connection on $TM$ restricts to a natural (Ehresmann; i.e. $n$-dimensional in your parlance) connection $H$ on $SM$, giving us a splitting $TSM = H \oplus \ker Dp$. In particular this implies $Dp|_H : H \to p^* TM$ is a bundle isomorphism over $\mathrm{id}_{SM}$, so we can smoothly identify $TSM = p^* TM \oplus \ker Dp$.

After making this identification, there is an obvious choice for your $(n-1)-$dimensional "connection": we can just let $T = W \oplus \{0\}$ where $W$ is the subbundle of $p^* TM$ defined by $W_{(x,v)} = v^\perp = \{w \in T_x M: \langle v,w \rangle = 0 \}.$